# Should I create a PyTorch Dataset to train a model off a pyspark dataframe?

Tags: python, pyspark, pytorch, huggingface-tokenizers, petastorm

I want to train a PyTorch NLP model over training data in columnar format, and I thought to construct a PyTorch `Dataset` using as raw data a pyspark dataframe (not sure it's the right approach...).

To preprocess text I'm using a tokenizer provided by the `transformers` library and a `tokenizing_UDF` function to apply the tokenization.

The `Dataset` object is then fed to a `DataLoader` to train a ML model.

What I currently have is this:

```py
import pandas as pd # ideally I'd like to get rid of pandas here
import torch
from torch.utils.data.dataset import Dataset
from transformers import BertTokenizer
from pyspark.sql import types as T
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')

text = ["This is a test.", "This is not a test."]*100
label = [1, 0]*100

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(zip(text, label), schema=['text', 'label'])
tokenizing_UDF = udf(lambda t: tokenizer.encode(t),  T.ArrayType(T.LongType())) 
df = df.withColumn("tokenized", tokenizing_UDF(F.col("text"))) # not sure this is the right way
df = df.toPandas() # ugly

class TokenizedDataset(Dataset):
    """needs refactoring..."""
    def __init__(self, df):
        self.data = df
        
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        text = self.data.loc[index].tokenized
        text = torch.LongTensor(text)
        label = self.data.loc[index].label
        return (text, label)

    def __len__(self):
        count = len(self.data)
        return count

dataset = TokenizedDataset(df) # slow...
```

I currently invoke `.toPandas()` so that my `TokenizedDataset` can deal with a pandas dataframe.

Is this a sensible approach?
If so, how should I modify the `TokenizedDataset` code to handle pyspark dataframes directly?
If I am off track, should I use https://github.com/uber/petastorm instead?

Comment: PyTorch forums https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/best-way-to-work-with-spark-generated-datasets/13601 don't seem to cast a particularly bright light on this topic apparently.

Comment: How much data do you have? I doubt that pyspark is the fast approach.

Comment: @cronoik it's around 2Gb training data. It's not huge at all, but the advantage I had in mind was to run the entire pipeline (ETL+model training) using Databricks. Something using pyspark for ETL and pytorch+petastorm+MLflow for model training should do the job but didn't manage to make it work yet.

Comment: I still think that you create a bottleneck here with the tokenizing_UDF due to the data transfer from the JVM to the python interpreter. Have you considered using a pandas_udf? Regarding your original question, have you check this [notebook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/_static/notebooks/deep-learning/petastorm-spark-converter-pytorch.html)?

Comment: @cronoik I'll check that `pandas_udf` option (I wasn't even aware of that...). As for creating a PyTorch DataLoader with petastorm, I came across that notebook and started modifying that code for my dataset, but so far with no luck... if I am not mistaken that alternative drops the creation of a `Dataset` entirely, so I would need to ask a separate question to ask for help.

Comment: Not sure if I get you wrong, but they load the `Dataset` in the first step. It seems that this dataset does not require any preparation and all the features are already present.

Comment: Maybe it's a tad clearer here @cronoik, seems to me that a `Dataset` is not needed when using `petastorm` https://github.com/uber/petastorm/issues/647 <- I asked a similar question to the library devs

Comment: What if your data doesn't fit in memory? How do you approach it?